# "%!s"-like error in fmt.Printf when format string is from arguments (go language)

Tags: go, format, printf

just see the code:(so simple that I can't believe myself)

```
package log

import "fmt"

func P(format string,a ...interface{}){
    fmt.Printf(format,a)
}
```

when called somewhere like this :

```
log.P("%s,%s,%d","","",0)
```

I got error:

```
[  %!s(int=0)],%!s(MISSING),%!d(MISSING)
```

BUT if I call fmt.Printf directly like this:

```
fmt.Printf("%s,%s,%d","","",0)
```

It works perfectly,just perfectly (of course,as basic use of fmt).

So the Question is:

### **Why log.P not work??**

FYI:

I believe it's pretty simple ,but I just can't find an answer by google,
never ever someone dropped in the hell ?

Or maybe I just dont know how to ask,so I put pure code above.

Or just I'm a super fool this time?

I signed up stackoverflow today for an answer to this. Let me know what's wrong with me. As soon...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a little mistake. You are calling `fmt.Printf` with `a` as a single argument, while it is not. You need to pass it as a variadic argument.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func P(format string, a ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf(format, a)
}

func P2(format string, a ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf(format, a...)
}

func main() {
    P("%s,%s,%d", "", "", 0)
    fmt.Println()
    P2("%s,%s,%d", "hello", "world", 0)
}
```

You can read about variadic parameters [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

Comment: Thank U,so I know sth called variadic argument.

Comment: I did the same stupid error :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `a` to `Printf` as variadic and to convert an array to variadic, you need to follow this notation:

```
func P(format string, a ...interface{}){
    fmt.Printf(format, a...)
}
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)
>
> [Passing arguments to ... parameters](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)
>
> If f is variadic with final parameter type ...T, then within the
>   function the argument is equivalent to a parameter of type []T. At
>   each call of f, the argument passed to the final parameter is a new
>   slice of type []T whose successive elements are the actual arguments,
>   which all must be assignable to the type T. The length of the slice is
>   therefore the number of arguments bound to the final parameter and may
>   differ for each call site.

---